# wso2 identity server - add new profile

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using wso2 identity server 3.2.3.
I would like to create a new user profile.
I connect as admin then go to My identity/My profiles but I don't see the "add new profile" button that should be located above the profile table.

How can I add new user profile?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered in the code that the LDAP user store managers doesn't support multiple profiles for a user. That's why the "add new profile" button doesn't appear.
To see it, I have to configure my user-mgt to use JDBC use store manager, or implement my own UserStoreManager.

See this extract of org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager source code :

```
/**
  * This method is to check whether multiple profiles are allowed with a particular user-store.
  * For an example, currently, JDBC user store supports multiple profiles and where as ApacheDS
  * does not allow.
  * LDAP currently does not allow multiple profiles.
  * @return boolean
  */
public boolean isMultipleProfilesAllowed() {
    return false;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```